# Perforce P4V resolve does not work

Tags: perforce, p4v

Using the current version of P4V I am trying to resolve a file.  When I click resolve on the file I get the following dialog.  As you can see the file to be resolved is not listed.  I cannot resolve interactively.  I cannot auto-resolve.  From here I am unable to proceed.

This is occurring on a new computer.  My workspace host is empty so I can get perforce to play nice with my previous computer's workspace.

I'd prefer not to manually resolve the file.  Is there a workaround or solution to this problem?

[image: about]

[image: resolve_dialog]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Perforce support:

> You're running into this issue because you're connecting a pre-2011.1
>   server. In the next release of P4V will only support 2011.1 server or
>   greater because of this issue for which no fix is scheduled.
>
> Therefore you have two options, downgrade to P4V 2014.1 which does not
>   have the issue:
>
> ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r14.1/bin.ntx64/p4vinst64.exe
>
> Or upgrade your server to the latest 2015.1 release.
>
> I think you should consider a server upgrade as your server release is
>   relatively old and you won't be able to use any newer version of P4V.
>
> Check this knowledge base article which explains how to upgrade your
>   Perforce server:
>
> Upgrading to 2013.3 and beyond

Comment: Was your workspace (especially pending changelists) preserved when you downgraded?